# Send or remember password in AcquireTokenAsync azure AD in xamarin forms

Tags: android, asp.net, xamarin, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Is it possible to send password in AcquireTokenAsync API of Azure. With current UserCredential only user name can be passed and user has to enter the password everytime. Is there a way to remember the password for the users?

Comment: Sounds like your token cache might be implemented wrong. It could be it's not finding a cached token in the cache, and so requires authentication every time. "Remembering the password" is not the solution, proper token caching is.

Comment: Have you checked the docs on Xamarin Android: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Xamarin-Android-specifics and AcquireSilent: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token ?

Comment: We getting the access token which expires every 60 mins once.so after expiration microsoft login page asks for login.. currently autofilling the username which is received from first authentication response. But is there any way to autofill the password as well ? want to user UserPasswordCredential which is not supported  in AD 5.0

Comment: No, there isn't. Your app should be able to get a new token with a refresh token, it should not need to ask for login every hour.

Comment: Ok. How can we check if token is expired and has to be refreshed? We are making a call to AcquireTokenSilentAsync before an webservice call to check the same.. but after an hour it prompts for login.

Comment: You should not need to check. MSAL will check for you. Could you add some code, how you are doing authentication and what is your token cache setup (if one is specified).

Comment: UserIdentifier credential = new UserIdentifier(email,UserIdentifierType.OptionalDisplayableId);
 AuthenticationResult= await AppData.AzureActiveDirectoryContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,clientid,returnuri, platformParams, credential);
                    }

Answer (score 0):

With the tags, I understand you might be referring to .net library. This is a way to send a password as a parameter in both the library of Microsoft. this flow is not recommended. it will not succeed in every scenario and also not considered secure.

**Adal**: result = `await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new UserPasswordCredential("john@contoso.com", johnsPassword));` [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-username-and-password) )

**Msal** :  result = `await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes,"joe@contoso.com",securePassword).ExecuteAsync();` [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication)